# Tank Auth - getting the user info from the database

Tags: class, codeigniter, tankauth

I've created a function which withdraw the user data from the database:

```
function user()
{
    $user_id = $this->ci->session->userdata('user_id');

    if (!is_null($user = $this->ci->users->get_user_by_id($user_id, TRUE))) {
        return $this->ci->users->get_user($user_id); //model
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I'm using it like this in any controller:

`$this->tank_auth->user()->field`.

Its not convenient for me, so what I need to do, to get the user data like this?

`$this->user->field` or `$this->tank_auth->user->field`.

My second question, regarding the above function is this function:

```
function is_admin()
{
    if ( $this->user()->who )
    {
        return $this->user()->who === "ADMIN";
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

It does throw error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: libraries/Tank_auth.php

Line Number: 335
```

(Line 335 is `if ( $this->user()->who )`).

Why does this happend? Both functions are located in the tank_auth's library, so its supposed to work fine, but it doesnt.

I'll appreciate any help attempt.

Comment: You could set $this->tank_auth->user() as a variable like this. $user = $this->tank_auth->user(); which would allow you to access it's values like so $user->field. What are you trying to accomplish with the is_admin method?

Comment: @DougWallace I want to check if `$this->tank_auth->user()->who` is ADMIN or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this method to the users.php model:

```
function get_user_profile_by_id($user_id){
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

    $query = $this->db->get($this->profile_table_name);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();
    return NULL;
}
```

you can then for example add a varchar field userclass in the userprofile table and check if a user belongs to a certain class with:

```
$profile = $this->users->get_user_profile_by_id($this->tank_auth->get_user_id());
if ($profile->userclass = "ADMIN") {
...
}
```

Hope that helps.